# How To Handle Client Side Websocket Data Stream in React Native, As The State is Changing Frequently My Screen Are Getting Frozen

Tags: react-native, websocket, react-native-flatlist, client-side, data-stream

I am Acutally Building A Client Side Paper Trading App Using React Native From The Data Provided By The Data Provider using Websocket, Suppose If i Subscribe For 'A' and 'B' and .... , iam getting data of them in websocket stream..i tried using usestate to put the data in state and append that in previous state and pass it the component, it is rerending entire component as the state is changing too frequent as the data is changing very frequently... please help me how to handle a to frequent change in data

Note: It is a websocket stream and  too frequent state change casuing re-render is causing performance problem,, if there any possible effecient way to handle the too frequent data change in react native , please suggest ... and the data which coming in realtime just need to be displayed not to be saved and displayed on ui without effecting performance

Here Is My HomeScreen Code:

```
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, Image, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import HomeScreenChart from './HomeScreenChart'
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import Strikes from './Strikes';

const url = "WebsocketURL";
var ws = new WebSocket(url);

const width = Dimensions.get('window').width
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height
const SPACING = 12

export default function HomeScreen() {
var recieveddata = []
var requestArray = ["nse_cm_nifty_50","nse_cm_nifty_bank","nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43000_ce","nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43000_pe","nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43100_ce","nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43100_pe","nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43200_ce","nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43200_pe","nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43300_ce","nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43300_pe","nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43400_ce","nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43400_pe","nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43500_ce","nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43500_pe"]
const [marketData, setmarketData] = useState({})
const CallWebSocket = async () =>{
ws.onopen = () => {
var requestString = ''
for (var i=0;i<requestArray.length;i++){
if(i==requestArray.length-1){
requestString = requestString+requestArray[i]
}else{
requestString = requestString+requestArray[i]+','
}
}
ws.send('type=msubscribe&'+requestString+'&columns=20'); // send a message
};
ws.onmessage =  async e => {
var text =  new Response(e.data).text();
text.then( (res)=>{
recieveddata = []
var responsedata = res.split('\n')
for  (var i=0;i<responsedata.length-2;i++){
var tempdata = responsedata[i].split('|')
recieveddata.push(`{index:${i}, name:${tempdata[0]}, value:${tempdata[1]}}`)               
}
//console.log(recieveddata)
})
};
ws.onerror = e => {
console.log(e.message);
};
ws.onclose = e => {
console.log(e.code, e.reason);
};

}
useEffect(() => {
CallWebSocket()
}, [])



return (
<SafeAreaView style={{flex:1 ,backgroundColor:'#ebecee',shadowColor:'black',borderBottomStartRadius:10,borderBottomEndRadius:10}}>
<View>
<View style={{padding:20}}>
<Text style={{fontSize:30,fontWeight:'bold'}}>Marketwatch</Text>
</View>
<View style={{flexDirection:'row',marginTop:5,justifyContent:'space-around'}}>
<View style={{flexDirection:'column'}} >
<Text style={{fontSize:25, color:'#4c80cf', fontWeight:'500',textAlign:'center'}}> NIFTY 50 </Text>
<TouchableOpacity><Text style={{fontSize:30, fontWeight:'800',alignSelf:'center'}}>{marketData.nse_cm_nifty_50}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
</View>
<View style={{flexDirection:'column'}} >
<Text style={{fontSize:25, fontWeight:'500'}}> BANK NITFTY</Text>
<TouchableOpacity><Text style={{fontSize:30, fontWeight:'800',alignSelf:'center'}}>{marketData.nse_cm_nifty_bank}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
</View>
</View>
<View style={{width:width-20,borderRadius:5,backgroundColor:'#810a0a',height:60,justifyContent:'space-around',alignItems:'center',alignSelf:'center',marginTop:10,marginBottom:5,flexDirection:'row'}}>
<Text style={{color:'white',fontSize:25,fontWeight:'400'}}>Expiry </Text>
<Text style={{color:'white',fontSize:25,fontWeight:'400'}}>5-DEC-2023</Text>
</View>
</View>
<ScrollView style={{flex:1 ,backgroundColor:'white',width:width,marginTop:5,height:height}} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
<View style={{flex:1, padding:20,flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'space-between',marginTop:5,marginBottom:0}}>
<Text style={{color:'green',fontSize:15,fontWeight:'800'}}>CALLS</Text>
<Text style={{color:'black',fontSize:20,fontWeight:'800',textDecorationLine:'underline'}}>STRIKE</Text>
<Text style={{color:'red',fontSize:15,fontWeight:'800'}}>PUTS </Text>
</View>
<View style={{ borderBottomColor: '#ebecee', borderBottomWidth:2,}}/>
{/* <Strikes strike={43000} ce={marketData.nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43000_ce} pe={marketData.nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43000_pe}/>
// <Strikes strike={43100} ce={marketData.nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43100_ce} pe={marketData.nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43100_pe}/>
// <Strikes strike={43200} ce={marketData.nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43200_ce} pe={marketData.nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43200_pe}/>
// <Strikes strike={43300} ce={marketData.nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43300_ce} pe={marketData.nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43300_pe}/>
// <Strikes strike={43400} ce={marketData.nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43400_ce} pe={marketData.nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43400_pe}/>
// <Strikes strike={43500} ce={marketData.nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43500_ce} pe={marketData.nse_fno_banknifty_05012023_43500_pe}/> */}
</ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
)
}
```

Comment: check new solution

Answer (score 0):

In case you are rendering computation heavy UI elements like charts, It is no brainer to update UI for each new stream data update.

Ideally, solution is debouncing stream updates for at least 2 seconds in order to update UI.

```js
function debounce(func, timeout = 2000) {
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(this, args);
    }, timeout);
  };
}

const CallWebSocket = async () => {
  // Minimum time to update UI for new stream data in milliseconds
  const STREAM_UPDATE_TRESHOLD = 2000;

  const onMessage = (e) => {
    var text = new Response(e.data).text();
    text.then((res) => {
      recieveddata = [];
      var responsedata = res.split("\n");
      for (var i = 0; i < responsedata.length - 2; i++) {
        var tempdata = responsedata[i].split("|");
        recieveddata.push(
          `{index:${i}, name:${tempdata[0]}, value:${tempdata[1]}}`
        );
      }
      //console.log(recieveddata)
    });
  };
  ws.onopen = () => {
    var requestString = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < requestArray.length; i++) {
      if (i == requestArray.length - 1) {
        requestString = requestString + requestArray[i];
      } else {
        requestString = requestString + requestArray[i] + ",";
      }
    }
    ws.send("type=msubscribe&" + requestString + "&columns=20"); // send a message
  };
  ws.onmessage = debounce(onMessage, STREAM_UPDATE_TRESHOLD);
  ws.onerror = (e) => {
    console.log(e.message);
  };
  ws.onclose = (e) => {
    console.log(e.code, e.reason);
  };
};
```